# declare variable with pd.read_sql_query

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pandas, pyodbc

Can someone explain why do I get an error when executing the following simple query with pandas:

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd

connstr = 'Driver={SQL Server}; Server=sr1; Database=db'
conn = pyodbc.connect(connstr)
query = """DECLARE @t AS DATETIME;
            SET @t = \'12-01-2020\';
            
            select top 10 AccountNumber
        FROM db.tb
          where ForecastDate >= @t"""


rt = pd.read_sql_query(conn, query)
conn.close()

ArgumentError: Could not parse rfc1738 URL from string 'DECLARE @t AS DATETIME;
            SET @t = '12-01-2020';
```

I understand that I can pass the variable `t` as a parameter to pandas and it will work, but I want to understand in principle what is causing the error, what are the restrictions on queries that can be passed to pandas. The query seems to work fine with `cursor.execute(query)`.

Comment: Why do you need to declare? Simply pass date into where clause via iso format: `'YYYY-MM-DD'`. Or pass as param from Python.

Comment: Yes, I can. I just want to understand what is the problem with the declaration in principle.

Comment: First argument of [`read_sql`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html) is SQL query string not connection object.

Comment: yes, not a smart mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You passed the arguments to `.read_sql_query()` in the wrong order. You used

```py
rt = pd.read_sql_query(conn, query)
```

when it should be

```py
rt = pd.read_sql_query(query, conn)
```